# How to assign and extract table values defined in RECORD type

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql, record

Here is sample code

```
CREATE TYPE entity AS
(
    record_init boolean,
    b_modified boolean,
    custom_name character varying(8000),
    customer_rec customer,     --- customer is a table 
    lang_pref boolean,
)
```

```
do 
$$
declare 
entity_rec entity;
Begin

    entity_rec.record_init := TRUE;
    entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id := 100;
    raise notice ' Customer Id is %', entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id;
end;
$$;
```

getting an error while referring customer_id from entity_rec.customer_rec

Comment: What exactly is the error you get.

Comment: ERROR:  "entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id" is not a known variable
LINE 13: entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id = 100;
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLpgSQL doesn't support complex expressions on left side of assign statement. You should to divide this operation to more operations (this issue is fixed in prepared PostgreSQL 14):

```
DECLARE
  entity_rec entity;
  customer_rec customer;
BEGIN
  entity_rec.record_init := TRUE;
  customer_rec.customer_id := 100;
  entity_rec.customer_rec := customer_rec;
  raise notice ' Customer Id is %', entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id;
END;
```

Second issue can be dereference of nested records. Postgres by default uses schema `schema`.`table`.`name`. When you use nested composite values, then the parenthesis should be used:

```
postgres=# do $$
DECLARE
  entity_rec entity;
  customer_rec customer;
BEGIN
  entity_rec.record_init := TRUE;
  customer_rec.customer_id := 100;
  entity_rec.customer_rec := customer_rec;
  raise notice ' Customer Id is %', entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id;
END;
$$;
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "customer_rec"
LINE 1: SELECT entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT entity_rec.customer_rec.customer_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at RAISE
```

Correct:

```
postgres=# do $$
DECLARE
  entity_rec entity;
  customer_rec customer;
BEGIN
  entity_rec.record_init := TRUE;
  customer_rec.customer_id := 100;
  entity_rec.customer_rec := customer_rec;
  raise notice ' Customer Id is %', (entity_rec).customer_rec.customer_id;
END;
$$;
NOTICE:   Customer Id is 100
DO
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, I followed your steps and it worked. really appreciated your efforts and time Thank you so much !!!

Comment: @EAPLHyderabad :)

Comment: @EAPLHyderabad: If that answers your question, consider accepting the answer.